# How can I copy regular Chrome's LocalStorage/SessionStorage/Cookies to NodeJS Puppeteer browser?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to automate an web application `https://webapp.com` in nodejs puppeteer application. The user is already using the web application in their regular google chrome browser (logged in and all). In my puppeteer application, i did `await page.goto('https://webapp.com');.
Since most of the users already logged in to their regular google chrome, i want to skip the login part in the puppeteer app by copying the webapp.com login datas like LocalStorage/SessionStorage or Cookies to the puppeteer browser.
Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried to read chrome user data directory, but it has some `ldb` files. I also tried to use the same browser in puppeteer by `launchOptions.executablePath='path/to/regular/chrome/browser'`. But the webapp logged out.

Comment: you would have to navigate to the page, set the localStorage and then reload the page ..

Comment: It seems to work if I provide the regular chrome user data directory.